# How to exchange data between a windows 2008 server and a linux server

Tags: c#, .net, soap

I have a Windows 2008 server on which I run a web application. The application receives user inputs {x,y,z} every few seconds, and I perform certain operations on them to achieve results {a,b,c}. Once this is done, I store a,b,c in SQL server 2008 on the windows server.

I have now setup another web application on a Linux server, on which I need to display these results {a,b,c}, in realtime (or almost), as they are produced in my windows server.

For each record, or set of records that I receive on the Linux VPS, I'll need to return an acknowledgement which gets reflected/ stored in the SQL Server in the Windows server.

What are the options to achieve this?

I'm thinking a C# SOAP client in the windows VPS with a tornado/python SOAP server in the Linux VPS over https?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) or [Redis](http://redis.io/)